# How to Parse this JSON converted from xml?

Tags: jquery

I got an `object` after converting from `XML` which contains `@attributes` as property. I've tried to get the value, but it returns `undefined` always.

The following object is what I get after converting from XML:

```
 {
    a:value;
    b:value;
    c:Array[2]
        0:Object
        1:Object
            @attributes : Object
                Name1: value1
                Name2: value2
                Name3: value3
                Name4: value4

}
```

Comment: That is not a json. Please add the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're talking about a normal `object` and not a `JSON`. So to access an property with such a name, you have to use the name as string.

```js
var data = {
  a: "value",
  b: "value",
  c: [{
    "@attributes": {
      Name1: "value1",
      Name2: "value2",
      Name3: "value3",
      Name4: "value4"
    }
  }, {
    "@attributes": {
      Name1: "value1",
      Name2: "value2",
      Name3: "value3",
      Name4: "value4"
    }
  }]
};

console.log(data.c[1]["@attributes"].Name1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply eisbehr. But when i try to access the value like what you said it return the value as 'undefined'.

Comment: Thank for your reply eisbehr. Its working fine. Thanks a lot